# Problems with running jar files

Tags: java, jar

Introduction.

I love Minecraft. So I want to play it with my friends.

I downloaded minecraft_server.jar file, but when I run it I see "A Java Exception has occurred." When running other jar files, it just does nothing.

Also, the strange thing about it is that on my friend's computer everything is good. I looked over other topics here, but nothing seems to help me.
In one of those topics I saw the advice to run it from cmd, and it said:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<clinit>(PropertiesUtil.java:31)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:48)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:44)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.<clinit>(SourceFile:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.<clinit>(ProviderUtil.java:70)
    ... 5 more
```

I don't know anything about Java and how to work with it, so can you help me?

Oh, just mentioned that those jar files work in java directory, but I want it to work in other directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have user name with special characters you should try

1. Create a new user account without special characters. (Windows user)
2. Change the "Working directory" where Minecraft stores its data.
   Right click on 'Minecraft.exe' or 'Minecraft.jar' (the launcher) and press "Create Shortcut". Right click on the new shortcut that gets generated and press "Properties".At the end of the 'Target' bar, add

> --workDir %ProgramData%.minecraft

Press 'OK' and then run the shortcut.

copy/paste from [minecraft.net](http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/special-characters/)

It seems like it is a known bug [MCL-774](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-774)

Comment: So this problem can be related with username with special characters?